# Incomprehensible "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding a comment function for each note. The specific method is to add a comment after entering the show of each note, and it will appear immediately below the same web page, as shown in the following code:

```
<h1>Note name<%= @note.title %></h1>
<%= @note.content %>

<%= form_with(model: @comment, url: note_comments_path(@note)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @comments.each do |c| %>
  <li>
    <%= c.content %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

However, when I press the "Add comment" button, the browser is redirected to the "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." error message page. I can't find anything missing from the controller. Please tell me what am I missing?

This is part of NotesController

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :check_login!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @notes = current_user.notes.includes(:user).order(id: :desc)
  end

  def new
    @note = current_user.notes.new
  end

  def create
    @note = current_user.notes.new(note_params)

    if @note.save
      redirect_to "/notes"
    else
      redirect_to "/notes/new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @note.comments.new
    @comments = @note.comments.order(id: :desc)
  end
......
private
  def find_user_note
    @note = current_user.notes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

This is CommentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_login!
  before_action :find_user_note

  def create
    @note.comments.new(comment_params)

    if @note.save
      @content = comment_params[:content]
    else
      redirect_to "/"
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comments).permit(:content).merge(user: current_user)
  end

  def find_user_note
    @note = current_user.notes.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Comment: What does the server returns as error ? What path is it actually hitting with what method ?

Comment: actually hitting url is ```note_comments_path GET /notes/:note_id/comments(.:format) 
comments#index```

Comment: It should be a POST method, just add `method: "post"` to your form and check again. With a get method it hits the comments controller "index" action instead of "create" action (you get a 404 because the index action does not exist)

Comment: I wrote ```<%= form_with(model: @comment, url: note_comments_path(@note), method: "post") do |f| %>``` but it doesn't work

Comment: How does your config/routes.rb file look like ?

Comment: @Maxence this is not correct. `form_with` defaults to `method: :post`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Comment: Something really strange is going on here. Check the rendered  HTML source and see what the `method` attribute of the form is. If its POST then turn off JS to ensure that you don't have an event handler thats attached to the form.